# How to make the onPressed shadow transparent?

Tags: flutter, dart

**Problem**

I created buttons with custom shape. When the button is pressed, the shadow appears, but I don't need it.

**My solution**

I set the elevation to 0 ( `elevation: 0`), but it didn't disable the "onPress" shadow. I set the `highlightColor` parameter and the shadow color, but I couldn't remove it completely. Finally, I set the `shape` to the shape of the `child` Container, but it doesn't work in all situations, I would like to know how to disable the shadow.

**Example Code**

I was trying to set some properties in `ButtonStyle()`, but without success.

```
ElevatedButton(
        style: ButtonStyle(),
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Image.asset(
          'assets/mypic.png',
        ),
      ),
```

**How it looks like**

[image]

**Question**

How do I remove the shadow color in the corners? Can you give me an example of the Button with transparent "onPress" shadow?

Comment: please add some code so others can help you better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I solved it myself. So I wrote this code:

```
 TextButton(
      style: ButtonStyle(
        side: MaterialStateProperty.all(BorderSide.none),
        shadowColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.transparent),
        overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.transparent),
      ),
      onPressed: onPressed,
      child: Container(/* my child */)
    ),
```

Setting properties `shadowColor` and `overlayColor` to *transparent* actually solved the issue. It makes the effect of pressing button completely invisible.

So the **best** option is to make button the same shape as it's child, but my solution is OK when it's hard to work with child.

Comment: It's better to use GestureDetector instead of a button in this case. I understood it later